# Main thread error on simple app Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to get the Getting Started App on the Android site to run in Android Studio. I don't know why I would have the "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." error on such a simple app.

1. Nothing added to the code except whats in the tutorial
2. Changed the heap size to 128
3. Changed the Ram to 768
4. Nexus 4 API 23
5. The textbox and the button don’t show up. But I dont get any other errors.

It seems like something is missing but I don’t know what.

```
10-15 08:10:12.213 2304-2304/com.example.mike.nutrition I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-15 08:10:12.213 2304-2304/com.example.mike.nutrition I/art: Late-enabling JIT
10-15 08:10:12.216 2304-2304/com.example.mike.nutrition I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
10-15 08:10:12.286 2304-2304/com.example.mike.nutrition W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.mike.nutrition-1/lib/x86
10-15 08:10:12.595 2304-2322/com.example.mike.nutrition D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-15 08:10:12.607 2304-2304/com.example.mike.nutrition D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaba3db60, tid 2304
10-15 08:10:13.012 2304-2322/com.example.mike.nutrition I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-15 08:10:13.092 2304-2322/com.example.mike.nutrition W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-15 08:10:13.092 2304-2322/com.example.mike.nutrition W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xab944fe0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-15 08:10:13.140 2304-2304/com.example.mike.nutrition I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-15 08:10:13.667 2304-2304/com.example.mike.nutrition I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-15 08:12:06.378 2304-2311/com.example.mike.nutrition W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.010ms
10-15 08:12:10.380 2304-2311/com.example.mike.nutrition W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.298ms



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/button_send" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
I am getting this error:

```
10-15 11:45:28.829 1563-1563/com.android.launcher3 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView$ParcelableSparseArray instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x4. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
```

Comment: Try switching snapshot of emulator to host GPU

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've not designated enough RAM to your AVD. Try upping it to 2056.

Comment: I increased the Ram and the Hexm and that didnt help.

Comment: 2056 is an odd number, should be 2048?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: No, it's an even number. Just joking!